# Transaction created by non-miner node is not mined in private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I create a private chain, and setup two node, one is miner and the other one is not.
Block sync between two nodes is fine and send transaction through sendTransaction method is also fine.
But transactions sent by non-miner node with sendRawTransaction method or sendSignedTransaction method are always in pending statues and return null when using eth.getTransaction(hash) on miner node.
Here is response when i do txpool.
[image]